# Polymer element not displaying

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I am working on a Polymer website and am having some issues. I previously had my main logic in `index.html`, and I just moved all of the logic from it into a web component I created called `app.html`. The website worked fine when everything was in `index.html`, but when I put it all into the web component and created the element in `index.html` instead, the page is now blank. There are no script errors or anything.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="application-name" content="PSK">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png">

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <!-- build:js bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

  <link rel="import" href="elements/app.html">

  <!-- For shared styles, shared-styles.html import in elements.html -->
  <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
</head>

<body fullbleed unresolved>
  <joyce-app></joyce-app>

  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

app.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- Iron elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/communication-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="custom-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">

<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">

<!-- Neon elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/firebase-element/firebase-auth.html">

<!-- Routing -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-router/app-router.html">

<!-- My elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../styles/app-theme.html">
<link rel="import" href="../styles/shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="blog.html">
<link rel="import" href="artist.html">
<link rel="import" href="teacher.html">
<link rel="import" href="research.html">
<link rel="import" href="contact.html">
<link rel="import" href="login.html">
<link rel="import" href="simple-overlay.html">

<dom-module id="joyce-app">
  <template>
    <!-- Main Area -->
    <paper-scroll-header-panel main condenses keep-condensed-header>
      <!-- Main Toolbar -->
      <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="medium-tall">

      <div class="center horizontal layout fit">
          <div class="app-name">My Website</div>
          <span class="flex"></span>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" onclick="login.open()" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <paper-icon-button icon="account-square" onclick="{{logout}}" hidden?="{{!statusKnown || !user}}"></paper-icon-button>
          <template if="{{user}}">{{user.password.username}}</template>
        </div>

        <!-- Application sub title -->
        <div class="bottom bottom-container center layout flex fit">
          <div class="bottom-title paper-font-subhead">
            <paper-tabs id="nav" selected="{{selected}}">
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/"><iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/artist"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:brush"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/teacher"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:apple"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/research"><iron-icon icon="custom-icons:book"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
                  <paper-tab><a href="#/contact"><iron-icon icon="mail"></iron-icon></a></paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>

      <!-- Main Content -->
      <div class="content">
        <app-router style="display:none;">
          <app-route path="/" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="/artist" import="/elements/artist.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="/teacher" import="/elements/teacher.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="/research" import="/elements/research.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="/contact" import="/elements/contact.html"></app-route>
          <app-route path="*" import="/elements/blog.html"></app-route>
        </app-router>
        <neon-animated-pages style="height:100%" id="pages" class="flex" selected="{{selected}}" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
          <neon-animatable><joyce-blog></joyce-blog></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-artist></joyce-artist></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-teacher></joyce-teacher></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-research></joyce-research></neon-animatable>
          <neon-animatable><joyce-contact></joyce-contact></neon-animatable>
        </neon-animated-pages>
      </div>

      <simple-overlay id="login" with-backdrop>
        <joyce-login></joyce-login>
      </simple-overlay>
    </paper-scroll-header-panel>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'joyce-app',

        login: function() {
          var params = {};
          params.email = this.email;
          params.password = this.password;
          this.$.firebaseLogin.login(params);
        },
        create: function() {
          this.$.firebaseLogin.createUser(this.email, this.password);
        },
        errorHandler: function(e) {
          this.message = 'Error: ' + e.detail.message;
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I have been struggling with this for a week and absolutely cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am able to reference other elements instead of `joyce-app`

Comment: what is it log in the console?

Comment: Which version of Polymer are you using?

Comment: Nothing in the console. I am using polymer 1.3.1

Comment: Read the complete migration guide and update all your elements. Also try to load and use the other elements directly in index.html. This way you'll know whether they have the some problem or not. I make my polymer elements by copying the code of an existing elements (usually paper-toolbar) and then make changes to it. You can try the same. This way you'll know which step beaks it and then you and find the error by comparing it to your original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out! It looks like my styling from my `app-theme.html` was only applying to `index.html`, so it wasn't getting applied to my custom element.

Apparently the correct way to do this is to also have your theme in a `.css` file and import it into each custom element that you want to use that theme.

Answer (score 2):

The `<polymer-element>` tag is no longer used to define an element in the new version of Polymer.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration

Comment: Well that was silly of me. I fixed this and edited my post, but am still having no luck with getting anything to display.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add this to your index.html if you're having a reference error(polymer not defined)

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```